# Remove directory that is listed as "No such file or directory"

Tags: bash

I have a folder on an external harddrive that has a curious folder in it that shows up as "No such file or directory" when I do a directory listing. See screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

How do I remove this folder without formatting the volume?

Comment: (1) A nit-pick: how do you know it's a directory (a.k.a. folder), rather than a file, if `ls` won't show you any information on it? (2) Can you just remove the containing folder ("Trash")? (3) How was this thing created? Was the disk on a different system? Can you take it back to the system on which the `Alizé (wf-rip)` object was created and do the delete there?

Comment: @G-Man it was a directory originally (many years ago) however this might have changed when things went wrong with it. The system it was created on was an old laptop I've since disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd your.dir
find . -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Before running the "find", check carefully and ensure to be placed in the right DIR otherwise you'll do LOT of damages.

If you think is too-dangerous, you can check what will be deleted with:

```
cd your.dir
find . -type f -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

BTW: once I read, somewhere: "'find' is a great program. Learn of it!"

Comment: I get a similar result as in my question for a basic `find` in this 'Trash' directory: http://i.imgur.com/bpnJhxu.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to remove empty directories under your current directory

```
find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get a similar result as in my question for a basic `find` in this 'Trash' directory: http://i.imgur.com/bpnJhxu.png

Comment: @Marcel: please run the full command (then one with "ls"), adding a single quote before and after the curly braces:  (-exec ls -ld '{}' \;). Probably you've a filename with a "carriage-return" inside.

Comment: @DamianoVerzulli unfortunately exact same result. "`find: ./Alizé (wf-rip): No such file or directory`"

Comment: @Marcel: can you try with "find . -type f -exec md5sum --quiet '{}' \;"? Please post screenshot of the answer.